# Upload large files example with self hosted Nancy

Tags: file-upload, large-files, self-hosting, nancy

Can someone post an example on how to upload a large file (eg. 50MB) using NancyFx running in self-hosting mode. The file is expected to be sent from a webpage (method=post; enctype=multipart/form-data).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it hard to find documentation on how to upload files in Nancy but this [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/nancy-web-framework/file$20upload/nancy-web-framework/GS4X4diu8ZQ/YQqkPYnTEyYJ) points to [this owin hosting example](https://github.com/grumpydev/Nancy/blob/bc031972767ece944df63b14d32319129737a740/src/Nancy.Demo.Hosting.Owin/MainModule.cs#L33) which I found gave me the info I needed.

This doesn't relate specifically to large files in self hosting, but I figured the info might be useful to someone.

Comment: The link referred to in the above (Nov 28, 2012) answer isn't valid any longer because it's link to source repository and the underlying file has been amended since then. You can probably work out which bit Joel Mitchell is referring to anyway just by reading the code but if you use this link you're looking at the version of the file which was being referred to at that time : https://github.com/grumpydev/Nancy/blob/bc031972767ece944df63b14d32319129737a740/src/Nancy.Demo.Hosting.Owin/MainModule.cs#L33